# SQL latest date by

Tags: sql

Can someone help me get the latest date for each item id.

This what I have so far:

```
select  
    prod_order_number, 
    location_id, 
    prod_order_line_item_id, 
    date_created, 
    primary_bin
from p21_view_asap_production_order
```

[image: Picture of the output]

Answer (score 2):

just use `group by` as:

```
select prod_order_line_item_id as prod_id, 
       max(date_created) as latest_date
  from p21_view_asap_production_order
 group by prod_id;
```

*P.S. for some databases such as Oracle, aliasing for group by doesn't work, in those cases directly use the column's name(`prod_order_line_item_id`) for group by expression.*

Answer (score 2):

You need to `GROUP BY` the other columns and use `MAX` on the date.
Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
     prod_order_number, 
     location_id, 
     prod_order_line_item_id, 
     MAX(date_created), 
     primary_bin 

FROM 
     p21_view_asap_production_order

GROUP BY 
     prod_order_number, 
     location_id, 
     prod_order_line_item_id, 
     primary_bin
```